# Server Can't Find: SERVFAIL & Bind9 DNS Server Setup

Tags: 16.04, server, dns, bind

i'm trying to deploy a web app on a VPS server. The app build with Django and currently trying to serve files with Apache2. I'm  having trouble with DNS setup(bind9). The company i use does not help me with this.

**Could you help me to solve this issue that i have dealt with 3 days ?**

OS:

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.7 LTS
Release:        16.04
Codename:       xenial
```

_

```
nslookup example.com

;; Got SERVFAIL reply from 8.8.8.8, trying next server
Server:         8.8.4.4
Address:        8.8.4.4#53

** server can't find example.com : SERVFAIL
```

_

```
nslookup example.com 185.106.209.113

Server:         185.106.209.113
Address:        185.106.209.113#53

Name:   
Address: 185.106.209.113
```

When i go to http://185.106.209.113/ address, i can see Apache2 default page. If i type http://example.com/ throws me **DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN** error.

```
|-- [-rwxr-xr-x bind    ]  bind.keys
|-- [-rwxr-xr-x bind    ]  db.0
|-- [-rwxr-xr-x bind    ]  db.127
|-- [-rwxr-xr-x bind    ]  db.255
|-- [-rwxr-xr-x bind    ]  db.empty
|-- [-rwxr-xr-x bind    ]  db.local
|-- [-rwxr-xr-x bind    ]  db.root
|-- [-rwxr-xr-x bind    ]  named.conf
|-- [-rwxr-xr-x bind    ]  named.conf.default-zones
|-- [-rwxr-xr-x bind    ]  named.conf.local
|-- [-rwxr-xr-x bind    ]  named.conf.local.back
|-- [-rwxr-xr-x bind    ]  named.conf.options
|-- [-rwxr-xr-x bind    ]  rndc.key
|-- [drwxr-sr-x bind    ]  zones
|   |-- [-rwxr-xr-x bind    ]  db.185.106
|   `-- [-rwxr-xr-x bind    ]  db.example.com
`-- [-rwxr-xr-x bind    ]  zones.rfc1918
```

**named.conf.options**:

```
acl "trusted" {
        185.106.209.113;
};



options {
        directory "/var/cache/bind";

        // If your ISP provided one or more IP addresses for stable
        // nameservers, you probably want to use them as forwarders.

        forwarders {
                185.106.209.113;
        };

        dnssec-validation auto;

        auth-nxdomain no;    # conform to RFC1035
        listen-on-v6 { any; };
};
```

**named.conf.local**:

```
//include "/etc/bind/zones.rfc1918";

zone "example.com" {
        type master;
        file "/etc/bind/zones/db.example.com";
        allow-transfer { 185.106.209.113; };
        also-notify { 185.106.209.113; };
};

zone "209.106.185.in-addr.arpa" {
        type master;
        file "/etc/bind/zones/db.185.106";
        allow-transfer { 185.106.209.113; };
        also-notify {185.106.209.113; };
};
```

**db.example.com**:

```
;
; BIND data file for local loopback interface
;
$TTL    604800
@       IN      SOA     ns1.example.com. root.example.com. (
                              3         ; Serial
                         604800         ; Refresh
                          86400         ; Retry
                        2419200         ; Expire
                         604800 )       ; Negative Cache TTL
; NS records
@       IN      NS      ns1.example.com.
@       IN      NS      ns2.example.com.
@       IN      A       185.106.209.113

; A records
ns1.example.com.    IN      A       185.106.209.113
ns2.example.com.    IN      A       185.106.209.113
```

**db.185.106**

```
;
; BIND reverse data file for local loopback interface
;
$TTL    604800
@       IN      SOA     ns1.example.com. root.example.com. (
                              3         ; Serial
                         604800         ; Refresh
                          86400         ; Retry
                        2419200         ; Expire
                         604800 )       ; Negative Cache TTL
; name servers - NS records
        IN      NS      ns1.example.com.
        IN      NS      ns2.example.com.

; PTR Records
113.209 IN      PTR     ns1.example.com.    ; 185.106.209.113
113.209 IN      PTR     ns2.example.com.    ; 185.106.209.113
```

and firewall status:

```
To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
22                         ALLOW       Anywhere
80/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere
Apache Full                ALLOW       Anywhere
8000                       ALLOW       Anywhere
53                         ALLOW       Anywhere
22 (v6)                    ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
80/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
Apache Full (v6)           ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
8000 (v6)                  ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
53 (v6)                    ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```

Comment: I deleted my answer. I realized it was incorrect for what you want. I only a run a local bind9 DNS, but leave the external world DNS management of my domain to my ISP, but managed by me. So, internally, my domain looks up as a local only address, 192.168.111.1, whereas externally it is a WAN IP address.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So go by these steps it worked for me and I'm sure it will work for you.

1.Set your hostname equal to one of your ServerNames like:

> server.example.com

---

2.configure the interfaces in /etc/network/ like:

```
iface ens3 inet static
address 192.168.1.10
netmask 255.255.255.0
```

*don't forget to restart 'networking'.*

now let's config the bind.
You don't need to edit all of the dbs just do it like bellow:

open /etc/bind/named.conf.local
add this at the end of the file:

```
zone "example.com" IN {
type master;
file "/etc/bind/forward.example.com";
};

zone "1.168.192.in-addr.arpa" IN {
#1.168.192 is the reverse of 192.168.1 wit out the last part "10"
type master;
file "/etc/bind/reverse.example.com";
}
```

now in /etc/bind

```
cp db.local  forward.example.com
```

now edit forward.example.com

```
;
; BIND data file for local loopback interface
;
$TTL    604800
@       IN      SOA     server.example.com. root.server.example.com. ( //Important dot(.) after domain names
                              2         ; Serial
                         604800         ; Refresh
                          86400         ; Retry
                        2419200         ; Expire
                         604800 )       ; Negative Cache TTL
;
@       IN      NS      server.example.com.
@       IN      A       xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx #your public static ip adress if you- 
server  IN      A       xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx #did you portforwards in NAT if you - 
host    IN      A       xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx #didn't import the static private ip-
client  IN      A       xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx #address.
www     IN      A       xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx

@       IN      NS      ns1.example.com.
@       IN      A       xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
ns1     IN      A       xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx

@       IN      MX      10 admin.example.com.
@       IN      A       xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
admin   IN      A       xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx

#this config contains email server configure too.
```

now in the same directory `cp forward.example.com reverse.example.com`

now edit reverse zone like bellow:

```
;
; BIND data file for local loopback interface
;
$TTL    604800
@       IN      SOA     server.example.com root.server.example.com. (
                              2         ; Serial
                         604800         ; Refresh
                          86400         ; Retry
                        2419200         ; Expire
                         604800 )       ; Negative Cache TTL
;
@       IN      NS      server.example.com.
@       IN      PTR     exapmle.com.
server  IN      A       xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
host    IN      A       xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
client  IN      A       xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
www     IN      A       xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
10      IN      PTR     server.exapmle.com.
11      IN      PTR     client.exapmle.com.

@       IN      NS      ns1.exapmle.com.
ns1     IN      A       xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
10      IN      PTR     ns1.exapmle.com.

@       IN      MX      10 admin.exapmle.com.
admin   IN      A       xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
10      IN      PTR     admin.exapmle.com.
#the ten in above of hashtag is the end number of your ip 192.168.1.(10)
or xxx.xxx.xxx.(xxx)
```

forward and reverse zones are configured now.
naw follow the command:

```
sudo named-checkconf -z /etc/bind/named.conf
sudo named-checkconf -z /etc/bind/named.conf.local
sudo named-checkzone forward /etc/bind/forward.example.com
sudo named-checkzone reverse /etc/bind/reverse.example.com
```

the outputs should show that the zones are loaded and there is no error.

now restart bind.
if there was an error just use **journalctl -xe** and see the details more times it just a typo and mistakes like that.

now do these:

```
sudo chown -R bind:bind /etc/bind
sudo chmod -R 755 /etc/bind
sudo systemctl restart bind9
sudo systemctl enable bind9


ufw allow bind9
ufw allow 53
ufw allow 53/tcp
ufw allow 53/udp
```

go to /etc/network/interfaces again
add this in the end of file:

```
dns-search example.com
dns-nameserver 192.168.1.10
```

after that restart networking with `sudo systemctl restart networking`

nano this file now: /etc/resolv.conf

add these at the end of the file:

```
nameserver 192.168.1.10
search example.com
```

restart the networking
restart the NetworkManager

now ping/nslookup/dig ns.example.com or server.example.com

***NOW It's WORKING***

Comment: Thank you very much for your guidance, nslookup and ping commands work very well right now however on [intodns](https://intodns.com/diricangrup.com) there is few errors and i truly don't understand them.

Comment: you're welcome @Alpcap , that's My pleasure

Comment: @Alpcap it's normal, search them in google they will solve easily.

Answer (score 2):

change in your file **named.conf.options:**

**dnssec-validation no;**

```
acl "trusted" {
        185.106.209.113;
};

options {
        directory "/var/cache/bind";

        // If your ISP provided one or more IP addresses for stable
        // nameservers, you probably want to use them as forwarders.

        forwarders {
                185.106.209.113;
        };

        dnssec-validation no;

        auth-nxdomain no;    # conform to RFC1035
        listen-on-v6 { any; };
};
```